# How to connect to a SINGLE colocated server - is StrongSWAN sufficient?

Tags: vpn, colocation, security

I am thinking of colocating a SuperMicro 1022G-URF (16-way 1u server, 16 GB RAM) at a "place that does server colocation.  I am running CentOS 6.  The server will be a web server and an email server (and DNS, if I can't find a way to outsource the DNS to a service).  I want to be able to connect into this server from "the road."  I have looked at a few scenarios.  I have ruled out SSH'ing into the box.  I find there are too many vulnerabilities in SSH and I want to use StrongSWAN.  I will be running iptables on the box.

Is it insane to set up a single server like this?  In other words...I get a dropoff from the server colocation company - that is it.  I am used to being in an environment with routers and switches and firewalls - this "single server scenario" is new to me.

Does anybody know of a better way of connecting to this single server?

Anything you could think of to help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are two many vulnerabilities in SSH, so you want to add another complex piece of software which has its own potential security problems? Seems a bit misguided to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anybody know of a better way of connecting to this single server?

Yeah. Use `ssh`.  IPSEC or a single-point VPN would be total overkill in my opinion.

---

There are not many (in fact there are currently ***no*** *known*) vulnerabilities in a properly configured OpenSSH setup, and *nearly everybody* is using SSH (most of us OpenSSH), so it's had a pretty thorough and complete security audit.
On the rare occasion that potential bugs are found they're patched very quickly, and vendors typically get those patches to their users in a timely manner.

My recommendation for you is to set up SSH correctly:

- Disable remote root login (`PermitRootLogin No`)
- Disable the use of Passwords to log in (require Public Keys)

  - Set a good passphrase on your  private key
- Optionally: Run SSH on an alternate port (something other than 22)
- Optionally: Use [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) or [pam_af](https://github.com/stass/pam_af) to blacklist persistent attackers

and ensure that you install patches when they come out.
This will give you a secure, stable, reliable way to connect to your system, and if something breaks it will be easy to troubleshoot.

Comment: You are correct!  Why my brain didn't think of using keys only...I have no idea.  Also - good idea - blacklisting! - Thanks!

Comment: @jim_m_somewhere Generally if you're only allowing logins using keys (and your keys are secure) blacklisting probably isn't necessary - that's why it's the last item on my list. My systems have anti brute-force measures in place because it is possible to authenticate using One-Time Passowrds (S/Key) as well as using SSH keys, and though the chance of someone brute-forcing the OTP pass phrases is extremely small I decided to err on the side of paranoia.

Comment: In my book - paranoia is good!  Thanks for the info!